I got down to it. | Does it mean "to hit the bottom" or "to start to do something"?
A famous person is telling a interviewer about how she fought with her illness, along with many other problems in her life (divorce, etc) during this process. At one point she said:

There was a part of me that felt like, wow, I lost so much. My career was basically over, my family was over, I got divorced, my child was taken away, a lot of my identity, I thought. I got down to it. Sharon stone on her brain hemorrage (see:3:12-3:21)

From the context, I understand she meant she was at her worst in health, life, finance etc., she was down in all aspect, but when I looked up "get down to it", it shows a completely different meaning:
1- to start to do (something)
2- to talk about or describe (something) in a very simple and accurate way
Is what I understand from the sentence not right?

She says "I got down,  down to it..."

@Yunus The famous person has to tell SOMEONE. The verb "tell" requires an object.

@RonaldSole, I did know that "tell" requires an object, but I didn't know that "tell about" also does. I have always thought "tell about" is a seperate verb. Anyway, I now have learnt. Thanks.

I believe the meaning here is not "to take up a task in earnest" but "to 'hit bottom' while having an existential crisis". The language is  colloquial,  pop-psychology. She says, emphatically

I got down ... down to it...

where "it" would be a state of mind where one asks questions like "to be, or not to be?"
She was questioning her identity (in the psychological sense)  and she realized "I'm not any of those things anymore".
As she said those words, she gesticulated, tracing a flat line while leaning slightly over. A related metaphor that one encounters in accounts of such crises is  "I hit bedrock".

It is a cliché here (UK) that people with a severe problem such as drinking or gambling 'have to hit rock bottom' before one may realistically hope they will seek help.

@TimR May I ask you a little side question? It's been a long-standing problem with me when it gets down to commenting:"TimR, I got into the spirit of the idea you HAVE proffered in your answer".  Is it relevant to apply Present Perfect here?  On one hand the relevant time zone leads up to the present (from your having written the answer, its presence up to the moment of my reading it and my looking at it at the moment of my response). On the other hand we both already know about the fact of your answer (I've read it) and, worse still, we see the time of your answer (20 hours ago). Thank you!

@Eugene It is idiomatic when referring to a text, even a small one like an answer here, to use the simple present (the point you make) or, in the case of a back-and-forth conversation, as is the case with comments, to use the present continuous (the point you're making).  However, the present perfect isn't wrong (the point you've made) and neither is the simple past (the point you made) if it's referring to a comment several comments earlier.

@TimR Thank you very much!

I think you may have misunderstood "I got down to it".  This isn't the same as "to get down" - in the sense of being depressed.
I note in the video she really emphasises the word "down", and repeats it several times. Here is the full quote:

There was a part of me that felt like, wow, I lost so much. My career
was basically over, my family was over, I got divorced, my child was
taken away, a lot of my identity, "I thought".
I got down, down to it. And when I got down to it, everything I
thought I'd been before, I thought, I'm not any of these things any
more.

When repeating the words "down" and "down to it", she seems to be having some difficulty expressing herself at this point and gestures downwards with her hands, as if she is trying to get down to the source of her problems/issues.
The OED has this definition of "to get down to it"

To settle down to (an activity, a topic, etc.); to turn one's
attention to. Frequently in to get down to it: to get started; to
begin work seriously or energetically.

However, given her gesturing, I would suggest this means she began to examine things, getting down to the fundamentals, so she could understand what the problem was, so that she could presumably begin to fix things or come to terms with them. It's not particularly clear however, and so this is little more than a guess. The quote cuts off right after this, and someone else begins talking. Perhaps if they hadn't edited it at this point she might have had more to say which could have clarified things.
You must also remember this is an edited clip of some colloquial English, mid-conversation, and she hasn't taken time to write any of this down or compose it. It's quite informal, and she is trying to express herself as best she can. Also the editing together of various clips here is not particularly helpful. We may not be getting the full picture.
I think that looking things up in a dictionary doesn't always help in such situations. We really need to look at the bigger picture, try to understand the context, hand gestures, and even the body language to work out what the person is really trying to say. It's not always entirely possible, as humans are fallible, and some are better at expressing themselves than others.


(1) to start to do (something)

is closer to the intended
meaning.  I prefer this OLD version:

to give serious attention to something

get down to
After all those things had happened to her,
Sharon Stone started to give serious attention to them.

Yes. If I started a task casually and without paying careful attention, but then got serious and worked hard, I might say 'then I got down to it'.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.   Agreed.
